# Do Generics always provide the type safety and under what optimal use cases

Tags: java, performance, generics, type-inference

I have worked with Generics in Java quite a bit and know about their type erasure capability and type safety.But there has been *some criticism about their occurrence in JAVA.*

My question is **what are the best optimized scenarios to utilize Generics and I am not talking about that '< E > void printArray' stuff**.Are there any advantageous usage scenarios or avoiding them will do.**Also in cases I have saw that they don't provide complete type safety.**

Now consider the code below:

```
// create a vector of strings
Vector<String> strings = new Vector<String>(10);

// cast it to a vector of objects
Vector<Object> objects = (Vector<Object>)strings;

// insert an object into the vector
objects.add(new Object());
```

---

Will the above code cause a runtime exception.No I test.It doesnt actually compile.

Now see the similar code using arrays:

```
// create an array of strings
String[] strings = new String[10];

// cast it to an array of objects
Object[] objects = strings;

// insert an object into the array
objects[0] = new Object();
```

Does it compile,yes despite the fact that casting a array of strings
to an array of objects introduces the possibility of run-time errors.

Line 8 demonstrates this, causing a run-time exception.

Now the type erasure should work in first example and let it compile and then cause a runtime exception as it worked in arrays example,because cast worked for array example at compile time using array type String[] which is analogous to the `vector type Vector<String>`   So Do generics  really help you at compile time? I think this behaviour is forced upon developers,because the parameterised types do not exist at run-time, and hence the variable created in line 2 of fist example just has type Vector.

**Also for what specifically helpful is Generalized target type inference in
java 8?**

Comment: Generics have nothing to do with the performance of your code, but rather with helping you implement your code in a way that you don't end up with some unexpected `ClassCastException`, thrown at Runtime. Since you already know what type erasure is, and that there is (almost) none Generic information at Runtime, why do you think Generics somehow affect the runtime performance?

Comment: Target type inference is specifically helpful for making your code less noisy by removing the need for redundant type annotations.

Comment: @KonstantinYovkov, I was not talking about runtime performence first and can you tell me what will the above code result in.

Comment: `Vector<Object> objects = (Vector<Object>)strings;` is an illegal type conversion. Your code doesn't even compile, let alone run without exceptions. The fact that it fails to compile is kind of the whole point.

Comment: @MarkoTopolnik I know it wont compile and will cause  an ‘incompatible types’ error and this implementation was chosen to avoid run-time exceptions.But  is this a problem when allowing casts of this form for arrays as java does.So the line 8 should cause a run-time exception.

Comment: I cannot parse your question. It doesn't compile, therefore it doesn't run, therefore it trivially doesn't throw an exception. If you rewrite to an analogous example with arrays, then it does compile, does run, and does produce a runtime exception. But where's the question?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/122983/discussion-between-khakishoiab-and-marko-topolnik).

Comment: Your newest edit adds the example I described in the comment above. My point was, what's your _question_ here? Generics are a static type checking feature and arrays are something completely different (and broken in terms of static type safety).

Comment: Do not use blockquotes for things that are not quotes. These are *your own words*; they should not be quoted. Blockquotes are not to be used for emphasis

Answer (score 1):

There is an interesting [study of Python modules](http://neverworkintheory.org/2016/06/13/polymorphism-in-python.html). It concluded that 97.4% of "variables" could be assigned "single static type using a conservative nominal type system using single inheritance". If we allow for parametric polymorphism in the type system (i.e. generics) this number increases by 0.5%.

This is one datapoint suggesting that the use of generic types in "real programs" is actually quite infrequent. Further anecdotal evidence may be found in many talks about the Go Programming Language, e.g. [this one by Brad Fitzpatrick](https://talks.golang.org/2014/gocon-tokyo.slide#50) "No generics. It sucks sometimes, but rarely."

Generics are a nice feature that allows the type system to capture a slightly larger portion of your program. It is also nice from the UX perspective, because it saves typing (with your fingers) and IDEs can offer autocompletion (compare that to doing manual typecasts to Object and back in Java 1.4). But generics do not appear that often and can be quite easily replaced by code generation and therefore seem to me to be hardly essential in software development.

(In fact, Go is cheating here. They do have generic types, but only for the 5 or so built in datastructures (maps, channels, ...). Users cannot define their own generic types and they cannot use generic type wildcards when specifying function arguments. Apparently, this suffices to satisfy the author of the presentation.)

Comment: But do they always provide type safety like in my example,its false

Comment: Not always. The Go talk has the "Haskell is useless" chart: Some languages aim for "getting things done quickly", (Python or C), while other aim at static safety (Haskell). It is a tradeof. In Java, you get a lot of static checking, but a successful compile does not guarantee the program will not crash (say on a Null Pointer Exception). Or you may miss a possible enum value in a case statement. So you still need unittests. On the other hand, if you write some algorithm in Haskell and it compiles, you are pretty much done (at least, that was my experience with Haskell at college ;)

Comment: The flip side of this is that Haskell just doesn't let you do anything it cannot prove correct. Like insert a log statement in the middle of a side effect-free function. It also means you have to spend much more time devising how to fit your desired architecture and behavior into the features offered by the type system.

Comment: True. Your first point means you still need the unittests, just not so many of them, and integration testing, and so on). Your second point is AFAIK reason why the slide is entitled "Haskell is useless".

Comment: BTW [Knuth's famous sentence](http://www-cs-faculty.stanford.edu/~uno/faq.html): "Beware of bugs in the above code; I have only proved it correct, not tried it."

Comment: A tangential note: the Go talk slides mention races and mutable state. There is also the Pony language, whose static type system proves the program thread-safe. Actor-based concurrent and async programming is first-class there.

Answer (score 1):

Due to type erasure the generic type information is lost during runtime.
Therefore the compiler makes sure that your first example does not compile otherwise it would cause a runtime exception.

Arrays are covariant, that makes this code compile

```
class A {}
class B extends A {}
class C extends A {}

A a = new B();
A[] as = new B[0];
as[0] = new C(); // runtime error, as is an array of Bs at runtime
```

But arrays in java have a reifiable type, that is for arrays the array type is known at runtime and therefore the assignment on the wrong element type causes an `ArrayStoreException` at runtime. tl;dr arrays are broken in java.

Read this for more information: https://dzone.com/articles/covariance-and-contravariance